# Systemd socket activated Redis client

Tags: redis, systemd, unix-socket

I'm building a system where Redis is used as asynchronous communication channel for different process on the same host. Some processes should in stand-by listen to XREAD or SUB for some event to happen and when it does they should do something and then shout down again until the next event happens.

Systemd's socket activation is what I would like to use for this but I don't how I can make it work since Redis uses unnamed sockets created in runtime and systemd seems to require that it creates the sockets itself before the services are started.

Any ideas?